# Is there any good chipmunk/cocos2d sample source out there?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm looking for sample to help me understand the how chipmunk physics works ... So I'm asking : is there any source code available out there ?

Comment: Official documentation : http://files.slembcke.net/chipmunk/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these out:

- [Bouncy Ball](http://iphonedev.net/2009/05/10/cocos2d-example-bouncing-ball/)
- [Collision & Particle System](http://morethanmachine.com/macdev/?p=105)
- [Moving Shapes With Touches](http://mobile-bros.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=297%3amoving-shapes-with-touches&catid=383%3acategory-technical-articles&Itemid=3)

Also, best place to get support is [here](http://www.slembcke.net/forums/viewforum.php?f=1).